# An ultimate-guitar API and usage of ultimate-api

Tags: python, http, github, client-server

I have this project in a DB course I'm taking this semester in which I'm required to build a web application and a design a DB for it.

The first step is to collect a large amount of records (At least 20k) which are music-related or themed. Now, I'm a guitar player myself so I wanted to do something with guitar tabs and/or chords and thought of using https://www.ultimate-guitar.com/ as a source for tabs and chords.

Unfortunately, https://www.ultimate-guitar.com/ does not provide an API that would allow me to easily access and retrieve a large amount of tabs. Luckily for me I found a couple of public GitHub repositories that seems to be what I need, even more so, one of them is in python which is the language of choice for this project.

Sadly, I am not versed in the ways of using external API's and I found myself unable to use the aformentioned repositories. I'm not sure if they are incomplete or if I simply failed to understand how to operate them. I tried cloning them using my PyCharm IDE but was unable to use them to get the tabs.

In an attempt to avoid writing something from scratch myself (which would take a considerable amount of time that frankly I do not have) I'm left with two choices:

1. Ask SO for help with figuring out how to use these API's.
2. Change the subject of my project.

Because it is a group project I would like to avoid the second option and so here are the repositories I found on GitHub:

1. https://github.com/joncardasis/ultimate-api (Python)
2. https://github.com/vincepii/uguitar-python (Python)
3. https://github.com/masterT/ultimate-guitar-scraper (JavaScript)

I've sent an email to the author of the first repository as it is the most promising of the three but because of time constraints I've posted this question simultaneously.

**UPDATE**

As suggested, I will speicify my question, how can I use ultimate-api to write a python client program that access the tabs.

Your counsel and guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to answer a specific question you asked: how to use `ultimate-api`.

First make sure that you have `python3` and `virtualenv` installed on your machine:

```
$ type -a python3
$ type -a virtualenv
```

If either of these commands does not return anything you have to
install a given program first.  Now go to the directory where you cloned `ultimate-api` repository and run:

```
$ virtualenv -p python3 venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You don't need to be `root` user to do that.

Now start the server:

```
$ python3 run.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 122-615-257
```

Go to `http://127.0.0.1:5000` in your favorite web browser, it should
say `hi`.  Now as the documentation of `ultimate-api` says you have to
use:

> A full (including protocol) url for an ultimate-guitar.com tab.

with `/tab` method.

Example:

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/tab?url=https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/_chk_chk_chk/intensify_bass_934215`

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/tab?url=https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/_chk_chk_chk/me_and_giuliani_down_by_the_schoolyard_a_true_story_bass_512135`

**Update**

Say, to get URLs for 100 top tabs:

```
$ wget -U firefox https://www.ultimate-guitar.com/top/tabs -O - 2>/dev/null | grep -F 'https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/' | grep -E -o '<a href=.+"' | sed -E 's,^<a href=",,' | sed 's,"$,,'
```

Now you can use this URLs with `ultimate-api` server.

Comment: I should've mentioned that I'm working in windows and I need to be able to do this automatically from within our yet-to-be-written DB code so a python script version of this would be great. In other words I want to be able to use this API from within my own code. I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Yes, you should have mentioned that.  What script are you talking about?

Comment: See my the update at the end of the question.

Comment: You can run `ultimate-api` server on your machine but I'm not sure if it
would work on Windows. `ultimate-api` server returns data in JSON so you would have to convert it somehow into SQL.  Alternatively you could also look into `ultimate-api` code and modify the part that formats data into JSON and make it work with SQL.